# Query builder doesn't work in laravel (pgsql)

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have a query builder that suppose to be like this in pure pgsql query

```
select distinct on(notulen.id) * 
from notulen 
inner join peserta_rapat on notulen.id=peserta_rapat.id_notulen 
inner join transaksi on transaksi.id_notulen=notulen.id
where "transaksi"."status"::text ilike 'DISETUJUI'
and (
    "peserta_rapat"."nip" ='197609072003121007' 
    or "transaksi"."nip_pimpinan" = '197609072003121007'
    or "transaksi"."nip_pj" = '197609072003121007'
    or "notulen"."nip_notulen" = '197609072003121007'
    or "notulen"."nip_sekretaris" = '197609072003121007'
    or "notulen"."nip_notulen" = '197609072003121007')
```

I build the same concept with laravel query builder but it's not working as expected

```
$t = Notulen::select(DB::raw('distinct on(notulen.id) *,transaksi.id_notulen'))
                ->join('peserta_rapat','peserta_rapat.id','=','notulen.id')
                ->join('transaksi','transaksi.id_notulen','=','notulen.id')
                ->where('transaksi.status', 'ilike', 'Disetujui')
                ->where(function($andWhere){
                    $andWhere
                    ->orWhere('peserta_rapat.nip','=',Auth::user()->nip)
                    ->orWhere('transaksi.nip_pimpinan','=',Auth::user()->nip)
                    ->orWhere('transaksi.nip_pj','=',Auth::user()->nip)
                    ->orWhere('notulen.nip_notulen','=',Auth::user()->nip)
                    ->orWhere('notulen.nip_sekretaris','=',Auth::user()->nip)
                    ->orWhere('notulen.nip_notulen','=',Auth::user()->nip);
                });
```

can someone help me to solve this problem??

Comment: What errors do you get? Those queries are not the same `notulen.id=peserta_rapat.id_notulen` vs. `'peserta_rapat.id','=','notulen.id'`

Comment: omg...what a ridicolous mistake...that's why it couldn't work.Thanks for the help sir.i've been working for 5 hours non-stop.I think i need to take a rest.

Comment: Not a problem. (5 hours ... "_You Gotta Pump Those Numbers Up, Those Are Rookie Numbers_") ;)

Comment: Hi, would you mind adding the solution to your problem as an answer and accepting it please so that others may benefit in the future? Thanks!

Comment: how to do that?